# TestNg | compiler always skip @Test(dataprovider) annotation

Tags: java, maven, testng-dataprovider

When i run my maven project , output giving as 1 test skipped. when i double click on the output it highlighted the`@Test(dataprovider="testdata") part in my code. 
apart from this code and pom.xml i have tried several other testng with A Data Provider annotated with @DataProvider and it also skip the @Test(dataprovider="") part.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QxN8H.png)

can someone please explain the causes for this issue: please refer below for the code and and the pom.xml file.

code :

```
 package Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;





public class DDTExcel
{
 ChromeDriver driver;
 @Test(dataProvider="testdata" )
 public void DemoProject(String username, String password) throws InterruptedException
 {
 System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\chromedriver.exe");
 driver = new ChromeDriver();
 driver.get("http://newtours.demoaut.com/");
 driver.findElement(By.name("userName")).sendKeys(username);
 driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys(password);
 driver.findElement(By.name("login")).click();
 Thread.sleep(5000);
 Assert.assertTrue(driver.getTitle().matches("Find a Flight: Mercury Tours:"), "Invalid credentials");
 System.out.println("Login successful");
 }
 @AfterMethod
 void ProgramTermination()
 {
 driver.quit();
 }
@DataProvider(name="testdata")
 public Object[][] TestDataFeed()
 {
 ReadExcelFile config = new ReadExcelFile("D:\\testData.xlsx");
 int rows = config.getRowCount(0);
 Object[][] credentials = new Object[rows][2];
for(int i=0;i<rows;i++)
 {
 credentials[i][0] = config.getData(0, i, 0);
 credentials[i][1] = config.getData(0, i, 1);
 }
 return credentials;
 }
}
```

pom.xml :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>au.com.simcentric</groupId>
    <artifactId>Example01</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.14.3</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.14.0</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sourceforge.jexcelapi/jxl -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sourceforge.jexcelapi</groupId>
    <artifactId>jxl</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.3</version>
</dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-remote-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.14.0</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.14.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.17</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-support</artifactId>
            <version>3.14.0</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hellojavaer/poi-excel-utils -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hellojavaer</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-excel-utils</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-xjc</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.13</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-java-commons</artifactId>
            <version>2.0-BETA19</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <version>2.44.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.opera</groupId>
            <artifactId>operadriver</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <version>1.5</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
                    <artifactId>selenium-remote-driver</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
    <groupId>com.tngtech.java</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-dataprovider</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.3</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <version>4.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-firefox-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.14.0</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>


    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <build>

<pluginManagement>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
      <version> 2.22.0</version>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</pluginManagement>
 </build> 
</project>
```

Comment: Please post actual output in your question, instead of a link to an image without a description.

Comment: I pulled in your screen shot, but I agree to the given comment. You should A) read [mcve] and then B) include all relevant code as well formatted/indented *text* within your question. That screenshot doesn't tell us what we need to know in order to help you.

Comment: @RolandWeber 
, GhostCat  Thank you so much for the feedbacks regarding my question and sorry for the inconvenience caused . i have updated and tried my best to explain the question above.

Comment: @ExperiencedQAengineer123 Without using Data Provider or TestNG annotation, by using Simple java program Execute your ReadExcel code. And check parameters.